# Will firedancer affect transaction finality time in any way?

Tags: transactions, validator, commitment

A bit of a silly question and I believe the answer is "no" but asking anyways... will firedancer improve the time necessary to reach `confirmed` or `finalized` commitment in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not initially. Quorum is achieved through consensus so we will not see any significant speed increase until the majority are running FireDancer or will be bottlenecked for confirmations from non-firedancer nodes :)